# Animation runs slower and doesn't replay without page reload in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, animation, html5-canvas, easeljs

Hi I'm following a tutorial in using easelJS for writing browser based games. And the tutorial is going fine but I've noticed some problems whilst playing the animations on chrome.

Chrome runs the animations slower and once played through once the same animation will not play again unless I reload the page.

Running in Firefox it doesn't have any of these problems.

Here's the link: (use inspect element for code)

http://david.blob.core.windows.net/easeljstutorials/easelJSSpritesTutorial03.html

I've heard there are some caching problems in chrome so I thought this might be the problem.
Manually deleting the cache does in fact allow the animation to play again without a page reload, but it still runs slowly (compare it to firefox).

As I want to code for cross browser compatibility is there a supported way in chrome to combat these problems? Such as blocking storing the images in cache or something? (A last resort I hope)

Thanks in advance,

Kyohei

EDIT: It seems the speed of the animation is the same on ie10 so not sure what speed it should be you know.

Comment: Your Description Sounds like Memory Overflow.

Comment: see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156837/javascript-speed-chrome-v-firefox

Comment: Caching will only affect the appearance after you changed an animation, it won't affect the speed! - Hard to say what your issue is, without taking a look at your code

Comment: @olsn thanks. The code can be viewed following the link in my question using a browser inspect element feature.

Comment: @SameerH.Ibra I followed your link but it seems opposite to mine. I seem to have faster animations on firefox than chrome and ie. Is there a way to force the browsers to show the animation at an almost exact speed?

Comment: @KyoheiKaneko : do you mean "How to make a JavaScript animation play at the same speed on all browsers on all systems ??"

Comment: @SameerH.Ibra yes that is part of the question. I saw that in the article it mentioned that there are differing speeds based on javascript processing speed but didnt seem to give a solution. Is the current method to keep the same speed by using animated gifs? And just travel them?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this will not work after a "reset" is that you are relying on the image load events to kick off the animation. This will work the first time, but the second time, the image is already loaded, and therefore you will never get an onload event from the images (meaning no "startGame()".

Since this is a simple example, maybe the best approach is to create new Images each time. Just move these lines into your init:

```
function init() {
    var imgMonsterARun = new Image();
    var imgMonsterAIdle = new Image();
    // Other stuff
}
```

Comment: I understand your reasoning and thanks for the reply. If this was tbe

Comment: ..the problem though wouldnt it be the same in ie and ff? On those browsers the animation replays fine when start is pressed? Also is there a way to avoid recreating the images each time as when I move on to my own games Id like them to be as efficient as pos? Thanks for the replies so far

Comment: certainly, and in fact, the above is bad practice. I was just pointing out that it fails because the onload never fires. Your start button should do something else. Like `if (alreadyLoaded) { startGame(); } else { loadImagesThenStartGame(); }

Comment: Ok cool np. If you update your answer to include the better practise above then I'll accept it as answer :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i read an article  [Fix your Timestep](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) it will help you , just need to convert it to javascript , read it carefully .